# SPARQL querying subclassOf: x some y

Tags: sparql, protege, fuseki

I have modeled an ontology using Protégé and have a class `ArchitectureFragment` with the following property:

```
SubClassOf: 
  modeledIn some Diagram
```

To perform SPARQL queries I use Apache Fuseki Server Endpoint.

I'd like to retrieve the information that `ArchitectureFragment` is `modeledIn some Diagram`.

How do I retrieve this subClass relation using SPARQL? When I just query for `rdf:subClassOf` I just get something like `_:b0` and I have no clue how to interpret that. I even tried querying for `_:b0` to see what it is but the results don't make sense to me. Is there any other way?

Comment: do you understand why? do you know RDF? do you know blank nodes? do you understand the [mapping of OWL to RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/)? if so, the query is simply matching the triples.

Comment: `?cls rdfs:subClassOf/owl:someValuesFrom ?y .`

Comment: Fuseki translates OWL to RDF, so I took a quick look at that code. I think I get it, but I'm not sure how to query what I want. I managed to do this:

SELECT * WHERE { 
  base:ArchitectureFragment rdfs:subClassOf ?subclasses .
  ?subclasses ?property ?value
}

but it doesn't seem to be possible to get the properties of _:b0 directly... I'd like to do something like: _:b0  ?a ?b. But the result doen't seem correct.

Comment: *"translates OWL to RDF"* - well, no. It reads an RDF file given that you provide the ontology in either RDF/XML, Turtle, N-Triples syntax. OWL axioms and class expressions usually map to more than a single RDF triple. Everything is explained [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/). Check for `ObjectSomeValuesFrom( OPE CE ) ` which is mapped to three RDF triples `_:x rdf:type owl:Restriction .
_:x owl:onProperty T(OPE) .
_:x owl:someValuesFrom T(CE) . ` Clearly, all you want is `CE`.

Comment: You have to understand that SPARQL is a query language for RDF, thus, querying OWL can be complex to impossible with a single query.

Comment: Of course ` _:b0 ?a ?b.` doesn't work. `_:b0` is a blank node, i.e. no identity. I already showed you the necessary triple pattern: `?cls rdfs:subClassOf/owl:someValuesFrom ?y .`

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the answer. It helped a lot!